# How to Make Text Transparencies when Collides with object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so basically when the player touches the platform, i want the text trasnparency from 0 to be to 1, Using unity3d

Here is the code:

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player2");
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont see any text object in the code you provided... or an attempt to change the alpha of the text.  So I am gonna flag this as cannot reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put a reference to your Text object inside your script, making sure to include the Unity UI objects:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
public Text textRef;
```

And then drag the Text object into it through the inspector. Inside your check for colliders, grab the Color of the Text object and change the alpha then set it back as the Color of the Text.

```
Color textColor = textRef.color;
textColor.a = 1.0f;
textRef.color = textColor;
```

Any questions?